# Altering HTML templates in vimwiki

Tags: plugin-vimwiki

The vimwiki plugin offers a great feature of converting whole Wiki to HTML: `:VimwikiAll2HTML`. But it bothers me that there are no back links to the main page, and the only way to navigate back to the main page is using the browser's "back" button.

Is there a way to modify the template vimwiki uses to produce HTML? Preferably without touching the plugin internals (I use pathogen and I want it to be portable between Vim installations).

Comment: You should accept your own answer. It seems to completely resolve the question.

Comment: @xthrd You can only accept your own solution when 48 hours have passed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution in vimwiki documentation. Here's a modification to my `.vimrc`:

```
let g:vimwiki_list = [{
  \ 'path': '$HOME/Dropbox/vimwiki',
  \ 'template_path': '$HOME/Dropbox/vimwiki/templates',
  \ 'template_default': 'default',
  \ 'template_ext': '.html'}]
```

I had to create `$HOME/Dropbox/vimwiki/templates/default.html`, and I took original HTML file content from `vimwiki/autoload/vimwiki/default.tpl`.

Obviously `$HOME/Dropbox/vimwiki` is to be replace with whatever directory your wiki is in.

EDIT: Wrote an article with more detail: http://www.rosipov.com/blog/custom-templates-in-vimwiki/